# Colour coding does not change colours in plot function

Tags: r, colors

I can't seem to change the colour coding with the following:

```
groups0 = factor(gsub('(.).', '\\1', country))

cols0 = c('green','red')[groups0]

plot(x, y,
 main= "",
 ylab= "",
 xlab= "",
 col= groups0, pch = 19, cex = 2, lty = "solid", lwd = 2)

reg1 <- lm(y ~ x)

text(x, y , labels=datta$City,pos = 4, cex= 0.5); abline(reg1)
```

the cols0 returns:

> cols0
>    [1] "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "blue"  "green" "blue"  "green"
>   [22] "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green" "green"

But on the graph it shows black dots and red dots. How to fix this?

(I tried this before with 4 categories, and I used four colors in cols0, and it worked)

Comment: `plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg, main="", ylab="", xlab="", pch=19, cex=2, lty="solid", lwd=2, 
     col=sample(c("blue", "green"), nrow(mtcars), replace=TRUE))` works fine so we really need all your data to help.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling groups0 for the colors, when it seems like you want to call cols0 within your plot function:

```
plot(x, y,
 main= "",
 ylab= "",
 xlab= "",
 col= cols0, pch = 19, cex = 2, lty = "solid", lwd = 2)
```

Additionally, it is unclear where you're getting 'blue' from, if the only input for cols0 are 'red' and 'green'.